# Working outside of application context. (Python: Flask error!)

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, flask, runtime-error

I am trying to build a skeleton-code setup for a new project.
In that case I need to use jsonify() which is imported from "flask", in order to make a str -> json.
However when I try to do this, I get a RunTimeError: "Working outside of application context".

When I google, I see a lot of people actually creating an app instance with Flask, but I do not need a app instance. I have seen people get this to work without making the app initialization (app = Flask(**name**)).

Anybody can explain what I am doing wrong?

This is my Controller:

```
# Standard library imports
import requests
import json
import logging
# Third party imports
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
# Internal codebase
from testing import TestObjects as testObj
from core import RequestHandler as rh
from intent import Heartbeat as hb
from intent import CenterCapacity as cc

class Controller():

    def __init__(self):
        # Key is the naming for action internally, value is the actual syntax for the action, mathcing the DialogFlow configuration.
        # If any actions change in DialogFlow, they should be corrected in the dictionary aswell.
        self.actionValues = {
            'getCenterCapacity': 'get.center.capacity', 'heartbeat': 'heartbeat'}

    def main(self, request):
        self.action = rh.getActionFromRequest(request)
        print(self.action)
        if self.action == self.actionValues.get('getCenterCapacity'):
            print(cc.getCenterCapacity())
        elif self.action == self.actionValues.get('heartbeat'):
            print(hb.emptyHeartbeat())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    c = Controller()
    c.main(testObj.getCapacityObj())
    c.main(testObj.getHeartbeatObj())
```

This is my intent "heartbeat" which causes the issue.

```
# Third party imports
from flask import jsonify


def emptyHeartbeat():
    print("You entered the heartbeat method!")
    msg = {
        "fulfillmentMessages": [
            {
                "text": {
                    "text": [""]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
    return jsonify(msg)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing the jsonify function with json.dumps https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html